# Combinatory categorial grammar for English

Tags: computational-linguistics, grammar, grammar-formalism

I am working on theoretical NLP things, in particular to do with combinatory categorial grammar (CCG). I don't have much knowledge of CCG, or of grammar in general.

I was wondering how much of English has been formalised in CCG? For instance, I've seen the following tables in a presentation on CCG. Is there a resource I can consult that has a big list/summary of different parts of speech of English with their corresponding CCG categories?
And as a follow up question, how much of English *hasn't* been formalised in CCG?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just dropping some references, haven't read in detail how much they cover: [Villavicencio (2002)](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-533.pdf), [Baldrige (2002)](https://era.ed.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/1842/562/IP020026.pdf), Beavers, J. (2003): A CCG implementation for the LKB, [Beavers (2004)](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C04-1009.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Are you aware of [CCGbank (Hockenmaier, 2003)](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/J07-3004.pdf)? This is the largest-scale corpus of English text annotated with CCG categories, consisting of ~1 million tokens of text, and is derived semi-automatically from the Penn Treebank.

This was used by [Clark & Curran (2007)](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/J07-4004.pdf) in a line of work to train wide-coverage dependency parsers for English, which made use of the fact that CCGbank covers a broad swathe of English syntax.

While the journal paper linked to above covers a number of the constructions handled, see Section 3 of [Julia Hockenmaier's thesis](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.135.8543&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for a complete list of the constructions that receive CCG analyses in the corpus.

It does cover rarer syntax which is nevertheless required for wide-coverage English text, such as conditional inversion ("Had it existed then, ...") which it analyses by assigning a category like `((S/S)/(S[pt]\NP))/NP` to the token "had", accounting for the inversion.

> Is there a resource I can consult that has a big list/summary of different parts of speech of English with their corresponding CCG categories?

Note that syntax doesn't map cleanly onto parts of speech, but you can easily gather a list of all categories that receive a certain part of speech by running some scripts on CCGbank directly.